# ¿Por qué al utilizar la función def para obtener una respuesta, esta no devuelve la respuesta deseada?

Tags: python, spyder, python-3.9

tengo que escribir un algoritmo que me permita hacer el pasaje de temperatura de grados Celcius (°C) a grados Farenheit (°F) y Rankine (°R), pero el código que formule me devuelve solo el par con la respuesta como si TempC fuera 0. (Dado que soy muy principiante, puede que no haya entendido como funciona el return de la función def
Adjunto el código

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

TempC=float(input("Ingrese temperatura en °C: "))

def Temperatura (TempC):
    K=TempC+273.15
    R=TempC*(9/5)+491.67
    return K,R

TempK=Temperatura(0)
TempR=Temperatura(1)

print("La temperatura en °K es: ",TempK) 
print("La temperatura en °R es: ", TempR) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

tu función retorna 2 valores (K y R)

Por ejemplo en

```
TempK=Temperatura(0) //asignara a TempK (273.15, 491.67)
```

Una posible solución es guardar esos dos valores en una variable e imprimirlos separadamente

Si utilizas

```
Temp=Temperatura(TempC) //asignara a Temp (273.15, 491.67)
```

pero puedes acceder a cada valor de la siguiente forma

```
Temp[0] // 1er valor 273.15

Temp[1] // 2do valor 491.67
```

y los imprimes adecuadamente con lo que el código quedaría de esta forma.

```
    def Temperatura (TempC):
        K=TempC+273.15
        R=TempC*(9/5)+491.67
        return K,R
    
    Temp=Temperatura(TempC)
    
    
    print("La temperatura en °K es: ",Temp[0]) 
    print("La temperatura en °R es: ", Temp[1])
```

Al ingresar 0 se imprimirá lo siguiente

```
Ingrese temperatura en °C: 0
La temperatura en °K es:  273.15
La temperatura en °R es:  491.67
```

Answer (score 1):

Como complemento a la respuesta de @Claudio Gutiérrez, quiero remarcar algunas cosas:

Estás confundiendo cosas, veamos una función:

```
def Temperatura( TempC ):
```

**Temperatura** es el nombre de la función, **TempC** es el parámetro que se le pasa a la función, dicho de otra manera, un dato que la función necesita para hacer su trabajo, osea si la llamo con:

```
Temperatura( 17 )
```

Me va a calcular las temperaturas en Farenheit y Rankine, equivalentes a 17 grados Celcius.
Ahora bien, puede llamar la función de esta manera:

```
temperaturasEquivalentes = Temperatura( 17 )
```

En cuyo caso, lo que devuelve la función (en este caso una lista) queda almacenado en **temperaturasEquivalentes**.

Luego para obtener cada temperatura, procedes como te indicó Claudio.